# how to align 2 rows in an info box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so i have these 2 rows of text displaying in an info box....but one row has an icon and the next one doesnt. i'm not exactly sure how to align the words so that the second row without the icon is indented correctly.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="alert alert-info">
  <i class="alert-icon-info alert-icon"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
</div>
```

it comes out like this

[image]

EDIT: also using bootstrap...if that helps

Comment: Show us your CSS please :)

Comment: which library are you using for icons??

Comment: i dont really have any custom css...just the ones from bootstrap

Comment: can you try creating a working snippet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to wrap everything in divs, I would suggest just wrapping your copy in a span and using flexbox to align your items.

HTML Edit:

```
<div class="alert alert-info my-alert">
  <i class="alert-icon-info alert-icon"></i>
  <span class="alert-copy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed</span>
</div>
```

CSS edit:

```
.my-alert {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/visioncreative/ufu6Lcud/3/

Great documentation on Flexbox at CSS-Tricks here, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Good point Peter. I have edited the answer to reflect your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to make a custom stylesheet, you should try `display: flex;`.
Creating container `span` for your text and then setting them to stand on the same line with `flexbox` is pretty easy then.

```css
.alert {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="alert alert-info">
  <i class="alert-icon-info alert-icon"><!--WARNING : remove the image, it's only there to demonstrate that it's working--><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Info_icon-72a7cf.svg/1024px-Info_icon-72a7cf.svg.png" width="20"/><!--END OF WARNING--></i>
  <span class="content"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed </span>
</div>
```

See here for a complete guide : [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)